# Ownership and inheritance within nested groups

Tags: azure, permissions, active-directory, azure-active-directory, az

If a user is an owner of Group1 and Group2 is member of Group1. My understanding was, user would be able to get ownership rights on Group2 also? I was trying to move the Onprem AD groups to Azure AD, was not sure how this will work. Any ideas? Please add any related articles.
Thanks

Comment: No, that's not the case. Until explicitly mention ownership of the at the Group 2 end. The user will not gain onwership access to the Group 2.

Comment: You could use Azure AD Connect to sync groups between On Prem AD to Azure AD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/concept-azure-ad-connect-sync-user-and-contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding was, user would be able to get ownership rights on Group2 also?

No, the user will not be able to get the ownership rights on Group2.

Looks there is no doc for the specific scenario, but I did a test to confirm it. I have a user account which is an owner of Group1 and Group2 is a member of Group1, then I use powershell [`Add-AzureADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) to add another user to the Group2 as a member, I got the `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`, it means the user does not have ownership on Group2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> I was trying to move the Onprem AD groups to Azure AD, was not sure how this will work. Any ideas?

You could use [`Azure AD Connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-whatis) to sync the on-prem AD groups to Azure AD, also see the [important points to be aware of when synchronizing groups from Active Directory to Azure AD.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/concept-azure-ad-connect-sync-user-and-contacts#groups)